# Error in my test class for ASP.NET MVC: error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a database-first ASP.NET MVC application with model, views and controllers made by MVC that I have heavily customized. I have a main project and a test project in my solution. My test code that tries to access the entities in my model is not working and throws this error:

Message: 
    Test method KurantCollections.Tests.Logic.KurantLogicTests.TestCreatingUserAndTown threw exception: 
    System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
    Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I admit I do not fully understand everything in the web.config file and I think I need to make my app.config file for the test project to match. Maybe the problem is that the model I am trying to access in the test class is not in the same project that defines it?

I am wondering if I provide the contents of the web.config from the main project and app.config file from the test project that someone might be able to tell me what is wrong or missing in my app.config?

Here is web.config for the main project in which the model is defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-KurantCollections-20191030015559.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-KurantCollections-20191030015559;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="KurantCollectionsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\jkura\source\repos\KurantCollectionsSol\KurantCollections\App_Data\KurantCollections.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Shared/Error" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

and here is the app.config from the test project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
    Note: Add entries to the App.config file for configuration settings
    that apply only to the Test project.
-->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>

    </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-KurantCollections-20191030015559.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-KurantCollections-20191030015559;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="KurantCollectionsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\jkura\source\repos\KurantCollectionsSol\KurantCollections\App_Data\KurantCollections.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Is there something glaringly missing here? I wish I better understood the meaning of all of this:

```
    <add name="KurantCollectionsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\jkura\source\repos\KurantCollectionsSol\KurantCollections\App_Data\KurantCollections.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I just added this to my app.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

and now I get this error:

```
Message: 
    Configuration system failed to initialize
  Stack Trace: 
    ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
    ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
    IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
    DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
    DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
    TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
    TraceInternal.get_Listeners()
    Trace.get_Listeners()
    TraceListenerManager.Add(ITraceListener traceListener)
```

Comment: Is your project 3 tiered architecture ?? In my case , I install EF in my library project by Nuget. I also install EF in my mvc project by Nuget. EF provider error fixed.

Comment: The EF is working in the main project.

Comment: It is a MVC project. I think the problem has to do with the app.config file needing to point to resources in the main project, but I admit I do not understand all of the syntax in the connectionString

Comment: i think it could be this, which is pointing into the main project: metadata=res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.KurantCollectionsDataModel.msl